# Bootstraps adds default padding? If yes How shall I remove it?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have added a animated header in my webpage project, but as I am using Bootstrap too, I get default padding shown in the following image (white spaces). [screenshot of the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhKpN.jpg)How shall I remove it?

I tried changing positioning in the css files, yet I had the left padding. Finally after removing the bootstrap, it works well.
[code](https://github.com/XQuestCode/temp)

Comment: Please can you share with us your html & css code? Thanks

Comment: please add [mre] and read [ask]

Comment: If you use the CSS !important rule, it will override ALL previous styling rules for that specific property on that element.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [code](https://github.com/XQuestCode/temp) If you download it, change the location of the CSS files.

Comment: instead of `.container` use `.container-fluid.p-0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple just remove `container` class from your html

```
<div class="demo">
      <div class="content">
          <div id="large-header" class="large-header">
            <canvas id="demo-canvas"></canvas>
               <h1 class="main-title">Internet <span class="thin">Of</span>Things</h1>
          </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```